# (Makefile) Multiple string replacement on the same line

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I have working makefile code which first finds all the files in the `u` folder, then removes `./u/` and finally replaces the back extension of `.c` to `.o` . Is there a way to make this a one or two-liner instead? I feel that this code looks messy and could be improved.

```
UTILS=$(wildcard ./u/*.c)
TEMP=$(UTILS:./u/%=%)
OBJ=$(TEMP:.c=.o)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't nest `$(var:x=y)` style replacements, but you can nest the equivalent `patsubst` function calls, so you could write this:

```
OBJ=$(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(patsubst ./u/%,%,$(wildcard ./u/*.c)))
```

Which  you can simplify to:

```
OBJ=$(patsubst ./u/%.c,%.o,$(wildcard ./u/*.c))
```

But with that simplification in mind, you can do the same thing with the original version:

```
UTILS=$(wildcard ./u/*.c)
OBJ=$(UTILS:./u/%.c=%.o)
```

Which is maybe easier to read.